# facebook sdk Graphrequest object returns null in android

Tags: android, facebook

i am trying to fetch facebook user details like name, userid, email,location,gender. i am getting response in log with user information but unable to store in session or sent to another activity, like form Login Activity to Main Activity bellow id my code in Login Activity

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LoginButton fbloginbtn;
    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private EditText username_login,password_login;

    Typeface tf;
    ProfilePictureView profilePictureView;

    AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;
    ProfileTracker mprofileTracker;

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private Session session;
    private Button loginbtn;
    private TextView register;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        session = new Session(LoginActivity.this);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

        username_login = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_username);
        password_login = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_password);
        loginbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_btn);
        register = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register);

        tf= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Roboto-Thin.ttf");
        username_login.setTypeface(tf);
        password_login.setTypeface(tf);

        fbloginbtn = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fb_login_btn);
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        loginbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String username = username_login.getText().toString();
                String password = password_login.getText().toString();

                if(username.trim().length() > 0 && password.trim().length() > 0){

                    checkLogin(username,password);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Please Enter The Credentials!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        LoginManager loginManager = LoginManager.getInstance();
        fbloginbtn.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
                //Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();

                getProfileInformationFacebook(accessToken);
                Log.e("login res", loginResult.toString());


                session.setFblogin(true);
               //Intent fblogin = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
               //startActivity(fblogin);
               //finish();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Your Login is Cancel ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "error to Login Facebook", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

    }



    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    }

    private void checkLogin(final String username, final String password) {
        String tag_string_req = "req_login";

        progressDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
        showDialog();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                AppURLs.URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                hideDialog();

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    String userId = jObj.getString("user_id");
                    String uname = jObj.getString("uname");

                    //JSONObject subObj = new JSONObject("user");
                    //String userName = subObj.getString("name");

                    if (userId != null) {
                        session.setLogin(true);
                        session.setMember(userId , uname);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                                MainActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("user_id", userId);
                        intent.putExtra("uname", uname);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Post params to login url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("tag", "login");
                params.put("username", username);
                params.put("password", password);

                return params;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to  queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        if (!progressDialog.isShowing())
            progressDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideDialog() {
        if (progressDialog.isShowing())
            progressDialog.dismiss();
    }


//Exit on press twice
    boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;
        }

        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;
            }
        }, 2000);
    }

   // fb user informaiton
    public void getProfileInformationFacebook(AccessToken accToken) {
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                accToken,
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(
                            JSONObject object,
                            GraphResponse response) {
                        Log.e("object", object.toString());
                        String fbId = null;
                        String fbBirthday = null;
                        String fbLocation = null;
                        String fbEmail = null;
                        String fbName = null;
                        String fbGend = null;
                        String fbPropic = null;

                        try {
                            fbId = object.getString("id");
                           fbEmail = object.getString("email");
                           fbName = object.getString("name");
                           fbGend = object.getString("gender");
                            fbBirthday = object.getString("birthday");
                           JSONObject jsonObject = object.getJSONObject("location");
                           fbLocation = jsonObject.getString("name");

                            //fbPropic = "https://graph.facebook.com/\"+ fbId +\"/picture?type=small";

                            session.FbLogindata(fbId, fbName, fbPropic, fbLocation, fbGend, fbEmail);


                                Intent fbdata = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                fbdata.putExtra("fbid",object.getString("id"));
                                fbdata.putExtra("fbname",object.getString("name"));
                                fbdata.putExtra("email",object.getString("email"));
                                fbdata.putExtra("gender",object.getString("gender"));
                                fbdata.putExtra("location",jsonObject.getString("name"));

                               // main.putExtra("imageUrl", profile.getProfilePictureUri(200,200).toString());
                                startActivity(fbdata);


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,location,gender,birthday");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
    }


}
```

getting `NullPointerException`

in my main activiry

```
fbuname = (TextView) mHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
        fbuemail = (TextView) mHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.user_email);


        Bundle inBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (inBundle != null){
            String Fbid = inBundle.getString("fbid");
            String Fbname = inBundle.getString("fbname");


        fbuname.setText(Fbname);
        fbuemail.setText(Fbid);
    }
```

in in my logcat

```
E/object: {"id":"1913429202227853","gender":"female","name":"Asesha George"}
```

my imports

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.AccessTokenTracker;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.GraphRequest;
import com.facebook.GraphResponse;
import com.facebook.Profile;
import com.facebook.ProfileTracker;
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
import com.facebook.login.widget.ProfilePictureView;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
```

please comment if you have any doubts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this your updated method

```
 public void getProfileInformationFacebook(AccessToken accToken) {
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                accToken,
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(
                            JSONObject object,
                            GraphResponse response) {
                        Log.e("object", object.toString());
                        String fbId = null;
                        String fbBirthday = null;
                        String fbLocation = null;
                        String fbEmail = null;
                        String fbName = null;
                        String fbGend = null;
                        String fbPropic = null;

                        try {
                            if(object.has("id")){
                                fbId = object.getString("id");
                            }
                            else {
                                fbId = "";
                            }
                            if(object.has("email")){
                                fbEmail = object.getString("email");
                            }
                            else {
                                fbEmail = "";
                            }if(object.has("name")){
                                fbName = object.getString("name");
                            }
                            else {
                                fbName ="";
                            }if(object.has("gender")){
                                fbGend = object.getString("gender");
                            }
                            else {
                                fbGend = "";
                            }if(object.has("birthday")){
                                fbBirthday = object.getString("birthday");
                            }
                            else {
                                fbBirthday = "";
                            }if(object.has("location")){
                                 JSONObject jsonObject = object.getJSONObject("location");
                                 if(object.has("name"))
                                fbLocation = jsonObject.getString("name");
                                else
                                    fbLocation ="";
                            }
                            else {
                                fbLocation ="";
                            }

                            //fbPropic = "https://graph.facebook.com/\"+ fbId +\"/picture?type=small";

                            session.FbLogindata(fbId, fbName, fbPropic, fbLocation, fbGend, fbEmail);


                                Intent fbdata = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                fbdata.putExtra("fbid",fbId);
                                fbdata.putExtra("fbname",fbName);
                                fbdata.putExtra("email",fbEmail);
                                fbdata.putExtra("gender",fbGend);
                                fbdata.putExtra("location",fbLocation);

                               // main.putExtra("imageUrl", profile.getProfilePictureUri(200,200).toString());
                                startActivity(fbdata);


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,location,gender,birthday");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
    }
```

add `compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.2'` in build.gradle and change `import org.json.JSONObject;`
 instead of `import com.google.gson.JsonObject;` in your Login activity then `has` method working properly

Comment: email field not in your response that's why an exception is occurred in above method

Comment: so you need to add some  conditions

Comment: Error:(268, 37) error: cannot find symbol method hash(String)

Comment: please import org.json.JSONObject; and add     compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.2'
 in you build.gradle

Comment: bro its working i changed hash to has answer accepted. can you explain why its showing NullPointExecption

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143561/discussion-between-bhupat-bheda-and-asesha-george).

Comment: because in,E/object: {"id":"1913429202227853","gender":"female","name":"Asesha George"}  email and other some fields not available in the response.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better get information from response object

```
                    String email = response.getJSONObject().getString("email");
                    String firstName = response.getJSONObject().getString("first_name");
                    String lastName = response.getJSONObject().getString("last_name");
                    String gender = response.getJSONObject().getString("gender");
```

or Create Profile object

```
                    Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                    String id = profile.getId();
                    String link = profile.getLinkUri().toString();
                    Log.d("Link",link);
                    if (Profile.getCurrentProfile()!=null)
                    {
                        Log.d("Login", "ProfilePic" + Profile.getCurrentProfile().getProfilePictureUri(200, 200));
                    }

                    Log.d("Login" + "Email", email);
                    Log.d("Login"+ "FirstName", firstName);
                    Log.d("Login" + "LastName", lastName);
                    Log.d("Login" + "Gender", gender);
```

Comment: please see getProfileInformationFacebook() at bottom of the Login Activity.

Comment: I know it you have to change key value

Comment: then how to pass facebook userid and name in that key

Comment: Log.e("object", object.toString());
what's values? please print this value in onCompleted callback func

Comment: {"id":"1913429202227853","gender":"female","name":"Asesha George"}